# Domain Controller / DNS Issue - Creating Network of Virtual Machines for Development

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, domain-controller

First off I am a developer, and I a moving into the realm of distributed computing.

I need to create a development environment which consists of:

1. Many HPC Server 2008 nodes
2. Domain Controller.

... all as virtual machines.

I followed this guide to creating a domain controller: d3planet.com/rtfb/2009/11/09/build-a-windows-server-2008-r2-domain-controller/

When I try to connect to the Domain like so via the Computer Name/Domain Change window (twitpic.com/qru6d/full) ,
I recieve the error: [Error Message Window](http://web7.twitpic.com/qruqu)

The Error Reads:

> "
>   Note: This information is intended for
>   a network administrator.  If you are
>   not your network's administrator,
>   notify the administrator that you
>   received this information, which has
>   been recorded in the file
>   C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt. The
>   following error occurred when DNS was
>   queried for the service location (SRV)
>   resource record used to locate an
>   Active Directory Domain Controller for
>   domain 17B.CO.UK: The error was: "DNS
>   name does not exist." (error code
>   0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR) The query
>   was for the SRV record for
>   _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.17B.CO.UK Common causes of this error include the
>   following:
>   - The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not
>   registered in DNS. These records are
>   registered with a DNS server
>   automatically when a AD DC is added to
>   a domain. They are updated by the AD
>   DC at set intervals. This computer is
>   configured to use DNS servers with the
>   following IP addresses:
>   192.168.1.1
>   - One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child
>   zone: 17B.CO.UK CO.UK UK . (the root
>   zone) For information about correcting
>   this problem, click Help. "

The part which is interesting is:

> This computer is
>   configured to use DNS servers with the
>   following IP addresses:
>   192.168.1.1

That is the IP of the router, not the virtual machine with the domain controller & DNS.

This seems to be a common issue to newb domain admins such as myself.

(Remember, this is a network of virtual machines which are all able to see/ping each other)

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I can support more info as required, thanks.

P.S. Excuse the insertion of direct links & lack of images, side effect of my account having no rep as yet.  I will tidy up quesiton when I get the rep to do so.

**Update:**

Virtual Machine (VM) as a Domain Controller to create a domain which other virtual machines to join.

VMware Workstation with each VM using a Birdged Connection (connecting directly to network).  Each machine can ping the other machines.

**Answer:**

I have blogged about the exact steps taken to solve this problem here: blog.holsee.com/2009/11/windows-hpc-server-2008-development-environment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you running one of your AD controllers as a DNS server? If so, then you need to point your DNS requests to that server and not the 192.168.1.1 (which you said is your router). You can then configure your internal DNS server to forward requests that it's not authoritative for to an outside responder (or your router).

Comment: How exactly would I do this with Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: This was achieved by getting my network adaptor (on each machine wishing to join the domain) pointing at the IP of the DNS host.  I will blog about this a link from the question.

Comment: you can also do this with DHCP, which you should already have license to do with a Windows Server license. Option 006 "DNS servers". You should also explore setting up time sync, option 004 and setting your default gateway, option 003.

Answer (score 0):

By virtual network do you mean you're creating a VM with a domain controller for testing? If so (I assume you're using VMware here), but when you create a VM you have to assign it a network based on the virtual networks you've created on the ESX host.

Comment: Yes a Virtual Machine (VM) with a Domain Controller to create a domain which other virtual machines can join. 

VMware Workstation with each VM using a Birdged Connection (connecting directly to network).